# What replaced $child method after the 0.8 angularFire update?

Tags: object, set, firebase, angularfire

I was trying to set some info in my database using the `$child` method in angularFire, only to realise that it had been completely removed in the 0.8 version update.

I then looked to see what the replacement would be for this by reading this:

https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-07-30-introducing-angularfire-08.html

But that didn't shed any light on the situation.

If I got a situation like this:

```
$scope.validate = function() {
    //--- Some validation here ---//

        var userInfo = {
            firstname: $('#firstname').val(),
            lastname: $('#lastname').val(),
            streetAddress: $('#street-address').val(),
            city: $('#city').val(),
            zip: $('#firstname').val(),
            country: $('#country').val(),
            email: $('#email').val(),
            password: $('#password').val(),
            confirmedPassword: $('#confirmed-password').val()
        }

    $scope.registerNewUser(userInfo);
},
$scope.registerNewUser = function(userInfo) {

    var ref = new Firebase("https://pie-shop.firebaseio.com/");
        ref.createUser({
            email    : userInfo.email,
            password : userInfo.password
        }, function(error, user) {
            if (error === null) {
                $scope.storeUserInfo(userInfo, user);
            }
            else {
                console.log(error);
            } 
        });
},
$scope.storeUserInfo = function(userInfo, user) {

    var ref = new Firebase('https://pie-shop.firebaseio.com/users/' + user.uid);

    var sync = $firebase(ref);

    sync.$child(user.uid).set({
        firstname: userInfo.firstname,
        lastname: userInfo.lastname,
        streetAddress: userInfo.streetAddress,
        city: userInfo.streetAddress,
        zip: userInfo.zip,
        country: userInfo.country
    });
}
```

Where I need to set a key that's named `user.uid` (which is the id of a user) and this key should contain the info from the `userInfo` object, how would I do it now since `$child` is removed? I've been searching for hours but can't find anything on this that explains how to do it in angularFire specifically.

**Pre-posting note**:

After checking the API documentation [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebase-setkey-data) it says that just using `sync.$set({foo: 'bar'})` should work but in my case it doesn't do it for me either. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: It might be easier to help you if you say what `$child` used to do. Also: when you say that you checked the API documentation, please include a link to the relevant section so we can check what you read and see if there is room for misinterpretation.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Added link.

Comment: The blog which *sheds no light on the subject* says:  Our focus in AngularFire is to handle synchronizing collections and bindings. The goal has never been to just replicate the Firebase API with “$ sign” prefixes.

To facilitate this intent, we’ve taken out $child() and $on() in this release. The new factory methods will provide even better functionality than hacking the data with $on(), and it’s still possible to drop to the SDK level functions with $ref() in a pinch.

Comment: The API doc you've referenced uses `sync.$set(key, value)`, not `sync.set(value)`.

Comment: @Kato I meant that, it is a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what AngularFire's pre-0.8 `$child` method did. But it likely was related to Firebase's regular `child` method.

In that case instead of this:

```
var ref = new Firebase(...);
var sync = $firebase(ref);
sync.$child(user.uid)...
```

You can also do:

```
var ref = new Firebase(...).child(user.uid);
var sync = $firebase(ref);
sync...
```

Comment: Ye I tried that but it seems that it's not working either. It's really strange.

Comment: Your original code seems to have double `uid` use that I'm not sure what it's supposed to do: `var ref = new Firebase('https://pie-shop.firebaseio.com/users/' + user.uid); var sync = $firebase(ref); sync.$child(user.uid).set({`.

Comment: That might be a typo that I've forgotten to change. I will try with just one.

Comment: It actually worked when removing one of the user.uid from the reference.